# Optimal strategy for moving groceries from car to the kitchen

Tags: optimization, soft-question

Let's suppose you have $m$ bags of groceries that cannot be taken home in a single trip  (if $n$ = number of trips, then $n\ge2$) from your car. Let $L$ be the distance from your car to your kitchen. Is it always a good strategy to walk the full path to get the next bags? I mean, suppose I define $L/2$ to be the place I will leave all the groceries before taking them inside. I grab the first $k$ bags from the car and leave them on the point $L/2$, then I return to the car and grab the next $k$ bags and so on. When I'm out of bags to move from the car I start to move them from $L/2$ to the kitchen.

I could define that the optimized variable is distance or energy, for instance, but I caught myself thinking about how to model this problem. It seems fairly trivial (I should always walk all path long and do $2n$ trips) but I can't find a way of showing that this is in fact the best strategy.

Comment: It's probably generally the same as long as you have a good place to lay bags at L/2 instead of unnecessary kneeling and crouching.  The one important factor would be whether you would have to open a door or something at L/2 -- then it might be important to lay all the bag outside the door, transfer all the bags just inside the door, then finish the trip to the kitchen.

Comment: I would think that as long as you are always carrying your maximum load, and as long as you don't split this load into multiple caches, then it makes no difference. Where it gets interesting is if the kitchen is so far from the car that you need to eat some of your groceries before you are finished. Obviously it is better to eat groceries that are still in the car than groceries that you have already carried to the kitchen, but the optimal strategy may lie somewhere in between these two possibilities.

Comment: If the mass of $k$ bags groceries will have a non-linear effect on total time (say, $T$), then you have quite an interesting optimization problem.

Comment: Another possible consideration is whether the dog will eat some of the groceries if you leave them at some intermediate point.